# How to run 2 tasks in parallel in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have 2 tasks, Task-A and Task-B. Task-A has a return type of ResultSet and is returning 1000 rows at one shot from DB. This task is to be run 10 times cuz the DB has 10,000 rows(also consider the case where the total no of rows in DB is unknown). Task-B has void return type and just does Sysout. I need to pass the first 1000 rows returned by Task-A to Task-B and as the Task-B is operating over those rows, I want Task-A to run in parallel so that by the time Task-B finished operating over the first 1000 records, The next set of 1000 records should be returned by the Task-A. 
Please tell me how can this be done in java. Any code snippet if possible would be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at creating two threads (a consumer and a producer) joined by a queue for communication.   Example here:  http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/blockingqueue.html

Comment: By two tasks do you mean two threads, if not then have a look at this as it nicely shows how to use lambdas in Java 8 to easily kick off separate threads https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OpAgZvYXLQ

Comment: Thanks! This seems to solve my issue, will try :) @Chris K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Chris K, here key is to use blocking queue, I have tried to write one high-level solution: DBThread for Task-A and PrinterThread for Task-B, and a blocking queue of ResultSet which shared between both the threads:

```
class DBThread extends Thread {
   private BlockingQueue<ResultSet> resultSets;
   public DBThread(BlockingQueue<ResultSet> resultSets) {
      this.resultSets = resultSets;
   }

   public void run() {
      try {
         resultSets.put(getResultsFromDB());  //resultSets.put() call will block if the queue is full
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   private ResultSet getResultsFromDB() {
      ResultSet resultSet = fromDB();   //some method to get ResultSet from DB
      return resultSet;
   }
}

class PrinterThread extends Thread  {
   private BlockingQueue<ResultSet> resultSets;
   public PrinterThread(BlockingQueue<ResultSet> resultSets) {
      this.resultSets = resultSets;
   }

   public void run() {
      try {
         printLogs(resultSets.take());  //resultSets.take() call will block if the queue is empty
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   private void printLogs(ResultSet resultSet) {
      //print rows
   }
}

class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      BlockingQueue<ResultSet> resultSets = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(10);
      DBThread dbThread = new DBThread(resultSets);
      PrinterThread printerThread = new PrinterThread(resultSets);
      dbThread.start();
      printerThread.start();
   }
}
```